# WPF datagrid rowheader when binding to dataview

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I have a problem when I try to bind a dataview to a datagrid and trying to get it to display the first row as a rowheader.

My datagrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ReportDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="False"  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HeadersVisibility="All" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowReportDataGrid}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"></Setter>
                </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGrid_Style_Header}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,10,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGrid_Style_Header}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,10,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
```

What happens with this code is that the datagrid inserts a rowheader and then puts the data from the dataview in the rest of the grid, the rowheader is left empty. What would be a good solution to get the first column of the dataview to the rowheader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem with a style instead, like so:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.DisplayIndex, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGrid_Style_Header}" />        
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```